# Setting up config file to connect to remote host

Tags: linux

I am trying to set up my config file for ssh. When I work from home I connect to machine located remotely as follows

1. Tunneling to the machine via local port
   ssh -N -l poppop -L 2223:my_machine:22 my.domain.com &
2. Then logging to machine using
   ssh -p 2223 username@localhost

Please help me setting my config file so that I dont have to tunnel it every time to log in.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to tunnel, else you wouldn't be doing this.  Do you mean that you want to automate the tunnelling step?  How about putting these two lines into a script?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need config file. just run

```
 ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]remote-machine
```

this command will copy your publicKey to remote, then you don't have to give password everytime.

if you don't have ssh-key pair yet, you need to generate a key-pair first.

`man ssh-keygen` for detail.